# MST: Prim's algorithm complexity, why not $O(EV \lg V)$?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, spanning-trees

According to CLRS, the Prim's algorithms is implemented as below --

> $\mathtt{\text{MST-PRIM}}(G,w,r)$
>
> - for each $u \in V[G]$ do
>
>   - $\mathtt{\text{key}}[u] \leftarrow \infty$
>   - $\pi[u] \leftarrow \mathtt{\text{NIL}}$
> - $\mathtt{\text{key}}[r] \leftarrow 0$
> - $Q \leftarrow V[G]$
> - while $Q \ne \emptyset$ do // ... $O(V)$
>
>   - $u$ $\leftarrow$ $\mathtt{\text{EXTRACT-MIN}}(u)$ // ... $O(\lg V)$
>
>     - for each $v \in \mathtt{\text{adj}}[u]$ do // ... $O(E)$
>
>       - if $v \in Q$ and $w(u,v) \gt \mathtt{\text{key}}[v]$
>
>         - then $\pi[v] \leftarrow u$
>
>           - $\mathtt{\text{key}} \leftarrow w(u,v)$ // $\mathtt{\text{DECREASE-KEY}}$ ... $O(\lg V)$

The book says the total complexity is $O(V \lg V + E \lg V) \approx O(E \lg V)$. However, what I understood is that the inner `for` loop with the `DECREASE-KEY` operation will cost $O(E \lg V)$, and the outer `while` loop encloses both the `EXTRACT-MIN` and the inner `for` loop, so the total complexity should be $O(V (\lg V + E \lg V)) = O(V \lg V + EV \lg V) \approx O(EV \lg V)$.

Why the complexity analysis is not performed as such? and What is wrong with my formulation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The complexity is derived as follows. The initialization phase costs $O(V)$. The $while$ loop is executed $\left| V \right|$ times. The $for$ loop nested within the $while$ loop is executed $degree(u)$ times. Finally, the handshaking lemma implies that there are $\Theta(E)$ implicit DECREASE-KEY’s. Therefore, the complexity is: $\Theta(V)* T_{EXTRACT-MIN} + \Theta(E) * T_{DECREASE-KEY}$.

The actual complexity depends on the data structure actually used in the algorithm. 
Using an array, $T_{EXTRACT-MIN} = O(V), T_{DECREASE-KEY} = O(1)$, complexity is $O(V^2)$ in the worst case.

Using a binary heap, $T_{EXTRACT-MIN} = O(\log V), T_{DECREASE-KEY} = O(\log V)$, complexity is $O(E \log V)$ in the worst case. Here is why: since the graph is connected, then $\left| E \right| \ge \left| V \right| - 1$, and $E$ is at most $V^2$ (worst case, for a dense graph) . Probably, you missed this point.

Using a Fibonacci Heap,  $T_{EXTRACT-MIN} = O(\log V)$ amortized, $T_{DECREASE-KEY} = O(1)$ amortized, complexity is $O(E + V \log V)$ in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea seems correct. Let's take the complexity as 
$V(\lg v + E\lg v)$.
Then notice that in the inner for loop, we are actually going through all the vertices, and not the edges, so let's modify a little to
$V(\lg v + V\lg v)$,
which means
$V\lg v + V^2\lg v$.
But for worst case analysis (dense graphs), $V^2$ is roughly equal to number of edges, $E$, giving
$V\lg v + E\lg v = (V+E)\lg v$
but since $V \ll E$, hence
$E\lg v$.

Comment: What's $v$? A typo for $V$?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand this at all. What does it mean to say "Let's take the complexity as [expression 1]" and then "modify a little to [expression 2]"? You can't just assume the running time is one thing and then change it to something else.